# WorksheetFunction.Quartile equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, excel, math, statistics

We are currently doing a MS-Access to .Net web page project. In MS-Access VBA code they have used "WorksheetFunction.Quartile" function. Please let me know the equivalent function in C#.

Sample usage in VBA:

Q1 = WorksheetFunction.Quartile(arrY, 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following C# code

#### Method code

```
  internal static double QUARTILE(double[] array, int nth_quartile)
    {
        Array.Sort(array);
        double dblPercentage = 0;

        switch (nth_quartile)
        {
            case 0:
                dblPercentage = 0; //Smallest value in the data set
                break;
            case 1:
                dblPercentage = 25; //First quartile (25th percentile)
                break;
            case 2:
                dblPercentage = 50; //Second quartile (50th percentile)
                break;

            case 3:
                dblPercentage = 75; //Third quartile (75th percentile)
                break;

            case 4:
                dblPercentage = 100; //Largest value in the data set
                break;
            default:
                dblPercentage = 0;
                break;
        }


        if (dblPercentage >= 100.0d) return array[array.Length - 1];

        double position = (double)(array.Length + 1) * dblPercentage / 100.0;
        double leftNumber = 0.0d, rightNumber = 0.0d;

        double n = dblPercentage / 100.0d * (array.Length - 1) + 1.0d;

        if (position >= 1)
        {
            leftNumber = array[(int)System.Math.Floor(n) - 1];
            rightNumber = array[(int)System.Math.Floor(n)];
        }
        else
        {
            leftNumber = array[0]; // first data
            rightNumber = array[1]; // first data
        }

        if (leftNumber == rightNumber)
            return leftNumber;
        else
        {
            double part = n - System.Math.Floor(n);
            return leftNumber + part * (rightNumber - leftNumber);
        }
    }
```

#### Testing code

```
double FirstQuartile = QUARTILE(numbers, 1);
double Median = QUARTILE(numbers, 2);
double ThirdQuartile = QUARTILE(numbers, 3);
```

Comment: Also in order to understand the Excel QUARTILE please refer following link   http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/quartile.php   for test use following test array double[] numbers = new double[] { 10.5, 7.2, 200, 5.4, 8.1 };

Comment: Thanks. This is best code i found that gives result same as excel.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any wrapped up nice little function like that, though would be very helpful. I recommend installing math.NET 
http://www.mathdotnet.com/

Here shows all that is included in SortedArrayStatistics
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics/SortedArrayStatistics.htm

below is a quartile example that I believe meets your needs

```
using System;
using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double[] numbers = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        double a = SortedArrayStatistics.Minimum(numbers);
        double b = SortedArrayStatistics.LowerQuartile(numbers);
        double c = SortedArrayStatistics.Median(numbers);
        double d = SortedArrayStatistics.UpperQuartile(numbers);
        double e = SortedArrayStatistics.Maximum(numbers);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n", a,b,c,d,e);
    }
}
```

output

```
1
1.66666666666667
3
4.33333333333333
5
```

Comment: Thanks BVMCode, When I tried the Quatrile function for the array {1,2,3,4,5} in Excel it is producing result {1,2,3,4,5} (i.e. QUARTILE($A$2:$A$7,0)=1, QUARTILE($A$2:$A$7,1)=2, ...). Which one is correct.